# How to make this layout in css with grid?

Tags: html, css, grid

[This is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okbxd.png)

Please help me to build that whit grid css

`CodePen example here`: https://codepen.io/crisbrin_9797/pen/ZEEZvKQ

Comment: can you share what you have and what you tried?

Comment: Have you considered this? https://metroui.org.ua/v3/tiles.html

Comment: this is what i've tried  https://codepen.io/crisbrin_9797/pen/ZEEZvKQ

Comment: when i'm adding grid-row-gap it destroy my layout

Comment: It looks like it works fine in the codepen! Please explain exactly what you want and what you've tried, and add the codepen in your question.

Comment: @AliasDev the "e" block is not aligned to bottom, i want it to be at the bottom of container

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you tried expanding the height of the box?

Comment: @cristopher_123 if you can, edit your post and put the codepen.io link into it. I think people are downvoting you because they don't see that you have attempted to code this yourself already.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create three rows, and use `grid-template-rows` to make the middle one short:

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 6fr 1fr 6fr;  
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 550px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "a b c"
  "a e c"
  "d e f"
}

.item{border: 1px solid black}
.a{grid-area: a}
.b{grid-area: b}
.c{grid-area: c}
.d{grid-area: d}
.e{grid-area: e}
.f{grid-area: f}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item a">a</div>
  <div class="item b">b</div>
  <div class="item c">c</div>
  <div class="item d">d</div>
  <div class="item e">e</div>
  <div class="item f">f</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace **span 12** by **span 13** it will make your 'e' box touch the bottom. Like shown below in snippet.

```
.e{
     grid-row: 7 / span 13;
     /*   height: 260px; */
  }
```